# How to make a sticky sidebar 'roll up' or move when you scroll to the footer, so it doesn't get covered by it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As you can see in  [this codepen](https://codepen.io/simii/pen/LbVYXo), the footer gets covered by the sticky sidebar. And if I just change the z-index the sidebar gets covered by the footer. It not good either way.

Is there an elegant solution for this? Maybe scrolling up the sidebar a little when the footer gets in view?1

```
    <div>
<div class="sidebar">
  <h3>Sidebar</h3>

</div>
<div class="article">
</div>
</div>
<footer class="page-footer">
   <div class="content">
       ....
   </div>
</footer>

<style>
 body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  main {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
  }
.sidebar {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #E7EAEC;
  width: 20rem;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 5em 1em;
}
.article {
  margin-left:20rem;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Why not put the footer under the content, and leave the sidebar with the page's full height? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqdExO

Comment: your codepen seems like the same for me, sidebar covering the footer so I don't get what you mean.
Could you clear it up for me please?

Comment: Oops my bad I forked it but didn't save it. Here you go: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PbqwLR

Comment: Thanks. Its a nice solution but not optimal for me - as I have quite much footer content on the real website, it gets really cluttered if you reduce the size. And it looks strange for me too. Would prefer some other solution. But thanks, its just my peculiarity!

Answer (score 1):

I made one solution with scrolling sidebar on resize window. There are two events that we are listen: on `load` and on `resize`. In that events we need to get height of article to be equal height of sidebar.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var article =  $(".article").height();
    $(".sidebar").height(article);
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    var article =  $(".article").height();
    $(".sidebar").height(article);
});
```

If you want this solution to work change **position** from `fixed` to `absolute` for `.sidebar` element.

Here is example: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BQNoZo)

Check the code and please let me know if you want to this on other way.